# Firestore security rules without auth

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I stored my portfolio app data using Firestore and firebase storage.
There are no user inputs or registration in my app, it's a simple portfolio to show my works.
I want any user to be able to read the data coming from my firestore and firebase storage.

My current rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

The problem i have with this rules is that attackers can fluid my app with requests.
I even got warning email says
"Because your project does not have strong security rules, anyone can access your entire database. Attackers can read all of your data, and they can drive up your bill."

I do not have any sensitive data stored but i want to prevent additional charges from google.
How can i set my Firestore security rules to enable any users to read without auth but prevent attacks?

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Security Rules don't like when a database point is left open, while this is normally done with Security Rules and Auth, You can define the readability of the document based on a value from inside the document.

In this example, the document has a bool value for `Public`

```js
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Allow the user to read data if the document has the 'visibility'
    // field set to 'public'
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read: if resource.data.public == true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.
Assuming I'm writing your suggestion in my rules, what should i add inside my react app(and where)?
And does it only make the security warnings go away or it actually help to prevent attackers from getting to many requests, if so, how?

Comment: you don't need to add any additional requirements inside your react app, this is to prevent your project database from being locked down by Firebase. which should make all future warnings stop. 
there also isn't a means to write currently, preventing any direct abuse to your database only. you only need to add logic conditions for yourself and other clients on when and how to write which is a separate field from reads

Comment: i applied the rules you suggested and added to some of the documents "public" bool field set to "true". but no data shows at all, as if the security rules was set to false. i'm getting this error message : Uncaught Error in snapshot listener: FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.

Comment: double-check your string case equality. also know that this can be denied if you are querying since public could also be false. the code I provided is from Firebase documentation